# Using an interface inside of an enum

Tags: java, interface, enums

I'm messing around with enumerations and interfaces, however i cannot seem to add the 'moneyType' interface i had implemented to the enum, i've been unable to find the solution.
Basically: the moneyType is red underlined, and i can not find out how i can get it right!

```
package Se.lucas.Main;

public enum moneyTypes implements moneyType {

DOLLAR(moneyType, 15, "Dollar"),
 EURO(moneyType, 15, "Dollar"), 
  FRANK(moneyType, 15, "Dollar"),
   MARK(moneyType, 15, "Dollar"),
    POUND(moneyType, 15, "Dollar");

private moneyType type;
private int amount;
private String moneyName;

moneyTypes(moneyType type, int amount, String name) {
    type = this.type;
    amount = this.amount;
    name = this.name();
}


@Override
public int getMoney() {
    return this.amount;

}

@Override
public String getMoneyName() {
    return this.name();
}

@Override
public String getMessage() {
    return "got the message";
}

}

package Se.lucas.Main;

public interface moneyType {


public int getMoney();
public String getMoneyName();
public String getMessage();

}
```

I have not worked with enumeration and interfaces a lot yet.

Comment: By the way, Java type names conventionally begin with a capital letter; also, `moneyTypes` should be singular, since when you declare a variable e.g. `moneyTypes type = moneyTypes.DOLLAR;`, its value is singular.

Comment: If you're referring to the `moneyType` in `DOLLAR(moneyType, 15, "Dollar"),`, you can't use a type name there - that's like trying to pass `String` as a parameter. Just leave it out: you don't need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to pass `moneyType` in the enum list declaration, or have it in the constructor, just leave it out. The reason being each enum instance will be a `moneyType`.

```
interface MoneyType {
    public int getMoney();
    public String getMoneyName();
    public String getMessage();
}

public enum MoneyTypes implements MoneyType {
    DOLLAR(15, "Dollar"), EURO(15, "Dollar"), FRANK(15, "Dollar"), MARK(15, "Dollar"), POUND(15, "Dollar");

    private final int amount;
    private final String moneyName;

    MoneyTypes(int amount, String name) {
        this.amount = amount;
        this.moneyName = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int getMoney() {
        return this.amount;
    }

    @Override
    public String getMoneyName() {
        // moneyName is assigned the value of name
        // You were returning name();
        // Two different values, decide which you want to return.
        return this.moneyName;
    }

    @Override
    public String getMessage() {
        return "got the message";
    }
}
```

Now you can do:

```
MoneyType type = MoneyTypes.DOLLAR;
```

*Note that I changed the names of the interface and the enum declaration to conform to Java naming standards, specifically beginning with an uppercase letter. I also modified the fields of the enum to be `final` so they cannot be assigned after they are constructed.*

Answer (score 1):

This maybe ?

```
package Se.lucas.Main;

public enum moneyTypes implements moneyType {

DOLLAR(15, "Dollar"),
 EURO(15, "Dollar"), 
  FRANK(15, "Dollar"),
   MARK(15, "Dollar"),
    POUND(15, "Dollar");

private int amount;
private String moneyName;

moneyTypes(int amount, String moneyName) {
     this.amount = amount;
     this.moneyName= moneyName;

}


@Override
public int getMoney() {
    return this.amount;

}

@Override
public String getMoneyName() {
    return this.moneyName;
}

@Override
public String getMessage() {
    return "got the message";
}
```

Note :

1. You `this` were on the wrong side
2. you used `this.name()` which would return something like `DOLLAR` in `getMoneyName()` instead of (i think) `this.moneyName`
3. I renamed `name` to `moneyName` to not have conflict with enum `name()`

Final point : using an interface over an enum like this seems a bit too much, do you really need that interface ? You can add method to an enum without any interface.